# Toggle class with onclick and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, getelementbyid

I'm making an inventory page for a website. I want to be able to sort the items with check boxes. What i think i need is to apply a div class to each of them and use document.getElementsByClassName to change the display to none for the ones i want hidden.

Anyway i tried with document.getElementsById, but i could only change the first one with the corresponding Id. Apperarently i need to change the class. This is where im at now.

P.S The [sc:1 ] is shortcoder for wordpress. It seemed to work when i used Id.

```
<script>
 function toggle() {
       var e = document.getElementsByClassName('truck');
       if(e.style.display == "block")
          e.style.display = "none";
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
   }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme" onclick="toggle()">Dump Truck
<div class="truck">This is text that should hide</div>
<div class="truck">[sc:1 ]</div>
<div class="sweeper">[sc:2 ]</div>
<div class="sweeper">[sc:3 ]</div>
```

Comment: you haven't explained what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over the set that `document.getElementsByClassName('truck');` returns:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    if(e[i].style.display == "block")
      e[i].style.display = "none";
   else
      e[i].style.display = 'block';
}
```

[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a set of elements that match that class name, so you have an array of DOM elements: `[elem1, elem2, elem3, ..]`. You can't just simply set `[].display == prop` - you have to iterate over the set and set the display for each element.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. If you are willing to explain what exactly is going on in your code i would appreciate it. Bit of a beginner here.

Comment: @user2631279 -- I added a quick explanation in the answer

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for everyone's time.

Comment: @user2631279 -- Be sure to accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName('truck'); always returns the array list of all the elements that has the class "track", so even if you have a single element that has the class "truck" the getElementsByClassName('truck') would return the single element in an array.

Please note, get**Elements**ByClassName has the plural form of element which refers to a set of element items to be fetched.

For your case, you have to iterate the array items to get each element and perform operations.

Try the following code block instead

```
<script>
function toggle() {
   var e = document.getElementsByClassName('truck'); 
   // Get all the elements that has the class name 'truck', so for your example, 
   // there are 2 items and the array e would have 2 items (i.e. e[0] will have the
   // div element that has 'This is text that should hide' as the inner HTML and e[1]
   // will have the div element that has [sc:1 ] as the inner HTML

   for (var x=0; x < e.length; x++) {
       if(e[x].style.display == "block")    // Get the xth element's style
          e[x].style.display = "none";
       else
          e[x].style.display = 'block';
   }
}
</script>
```

Please note, even if you have a single item with the class name "truck" you would find it on the 0th location of the returned array (i.e. e[0]).